# Why is the position of my UISlider different on the IPad Pro?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uislider

I have this slider and its positioned correctly in all my devices except for my iPad Pro. Im using this code below to set the slider for my iPhone and iPad but on the Pro the positioning is off. How would I fix it?

```
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320
        let scaleFactor2 = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 480

        middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(120 * scaleFactor, 25, 150, 50))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb3"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        middleSlider.maximumValue = 2.0
        middleSlider.minimumValue =  0.0
        middleSlider.value = 1.0
        middleSlider.continuous = true
        middleSlider.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)
        }



        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {

        let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320
        let scaleFactor2 = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 480

        middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(110 * scaleFactor, 50, 300, 150))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb3"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        middleSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumValue = 2.0
        middleSlider.minimumValue =  0.0
        middleSlider.value = 1.0
        middleSlider.continuous = true
        middleSlider.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)

        }
```

Comment: You didn't called addSubView method in your iPad condition?

Comment: More info is needed. Please show images of what "positioning is off" means and an image of what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Evana That was an error on my part.

Comment: @RoboticCat So the slider is supposed to be in the middle of the screen and on the ipad pro the slider is to the left.

Comment: That doesn't help. What are the frame values for each slider? The problem is likely to do with your positioning of the slider since you are hardcoding it's frame.

Comment: When Im not hardcoding the frame the position for the ipad pro is still not the same as the other ipads.

Comment: FYI - you should not have any code that checks the device idiom. Everything should be based on parent view size and size classes. Otherwise your code won't properly adapt to different device sizes and it won't work properly on iPads that support multitasking.

Comment: Only thing im using the device idiom for is the sliders.

Comment: @rmaddy Im in spritekit so how would I postition the slider so that its in the middle of the screen for all my devices? Im not sure how to do that if I cant use the device idiom.

Comment: @coding22 programatically add contstraint to centre the uislider